# Add a blur view above the videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview, blur, uiblureffect

In ios, one can put a `UIBlurEffect` above the `videoview` and then the video will be blurred. I am wondering how can i do the same in android or how to blur the video in real time?
sorry for my pool English,but i really stuck here,i found a way to blur video with here [link](https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus),but it only support surfaceview,is there any way blur the video in textureview?